# Angular 6 - How do I set a Parent Menu Item To Active using routerLinkActive When Clicking on Its Child Menu Item?

Tags: angular, routerlinkactive

I'm using Angular 6 and I've ran into an issue regarding my navigation menu.

When I click on a child-item, only the child item is set to active and not the parent when using routerLinkActive.

I'm wondering how I could set the parent item class to active when selecting its child item in Angular 6?

Lets say I click Floor Maintenance which is the child of Services. Only Floor Maintenance will be set to active but not Services. I'd like to have the Services Button active using routerLinkActive when clicking any of its child items.

## Navigation Menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white thick-border-bottom">
  <div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink=""><img id="logo" class="img-fluid" src="./assets/logo.svg" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler my-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]={exact:true}>Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
      </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" routerLink="services" routerLinkActive="active" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
            Services
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="services/janitorial-services" routerLinkActive="active">Janitorial Services</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="services/floor-maintenance" routerLinkActive="active">Floor Maintenance</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="services/green-cleaning-services" routerLinkActive="active">Green Cleaning</a>
          </div>
        </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/our-difference" routerLinkActive="active">Our Difference</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/our-clients" routerLinkActive="active">Our Clients</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

## Routing Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './frontend/pages/about/about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './frontend/pages/home/home.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './frontend/pages/services/services.component';
import { JanitorialServicesComponent } from './frontend/pages/services/subpages/janitorial-services/janitorial-services.component';
import { ServiceAreasComponent } from './frontend/pages/service-areas/service-areas.component';
import { OurClientsComponent } from './frontend/pages/our-clients/our-clients.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './frontend/pages/contact/contact.component';
import { FloorMaintenanceComponent } from './frontend/pages/services/subpages/floor-maintenance/floor-maintenance.component';
import { GreenCleaningServicesComponent } from './frontend/pages/services/subpages/green-cleaning-services/green-cleaning-services.component';
import { OurDifferenceComponent } from './frontend/pages/our-difference/our-difference.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent, 
    children: [
      {path: "janitorial-services", component: JanitorialServicesComponent},
      { path: "green-cleaning-services", component: GreenCleaningServicesComponent},
      { path: "floor-maintenance", component: FloorMaintenanceComponent}
    ] 
  },
  { path: 'our-difference', component: OurDifferenceComponent },
  { path: 'our-clients', component: OurClientsComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
})


export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You'll need to add some code to your question so we can see what method you're using to set the parent from the docs: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: @Brandon I added code for the navigation and the routing module

Comment: Brandon you're absolutely right. Your code works but mind doesnt. I compared your code to mine and the only difference I saw is that I had the routerLinkActive on the <a> tag. I moved all routerLinkActive and routerLinks to its own <li> tag so every a tag is wrapped around a <li> tag and it worked! Thanks bud!

Answer (score 8):

So when I compared my code to https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-active?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css this.

The only difference I could find is that the routerLinks and routerLinkActive attributes that I was set to the a tags.

So i decided to to structure it like this instead:

```
<ul>
  <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <a href="#" routerLink="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li  routerLinkActive="active">
    <a href="#" routerLink="/parent">Parent Component</a>
    <ul>
      <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
        <a href="#" routerLink="/parent/child">Child Component</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I changed the StackBlitz to put the `routerLinkActive` directives on the anchor tags and it still works as expected.

Comment: Thank you.
It's nice to use routerLinkActive="active" for li.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the parent class to remain active while the child class is too, you need to set the routerLink for the child as /parent/child. If the beginning of the active routerLink matches exactly another one, both will become active:

```
<div>
    <a routerLink="/Parent" routerLinkActive="active">Parent</a>
    <a routerLink="/Parent/Child" routerLinkActive="active">Child</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @F Huerta  I made changes to my original post. You can see the navigation menu and routing module. Let me know if you're curious to see anything else. As it looks, i did as you suggested but no changes, the problem remains. When I click a child of a parent item; only the child item will be set to active and not the parent.

Comment: @leonardofjr This answer should work. Here's a StackBlitz example with the exact method employed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-active

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a template variable. Check the `#rla` variable in the child component.

```
<li [ngClass]="{ 'is-expanded': rla.isActive }">
  <a>Parent</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/child" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive">Child</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: #rla variable in the child component - If there are more child component then this method wont helpright because for each child component there will be different variable ..do You know if there are multiple child components then what will be the approach?